# Getting focus of Edittext drawn programatically in Android

Tags: android, json, android-edittext

I am trying to draw edit text programatically,based on my JSON response.All are drawn perfectly,but i can only edit the last one and the others are not editable ,and I can't get their focus. Any idea what would fix this?

```
  RelativeLayout layout =(RelativeLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.layout_items);
        JSONArray result=(JSONArray)o;
        for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
            try {
                relativeLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                 editText = new EditText(context);
                editText.setHint(result.getJSONObject(i).getString(config.TAG_NAME));
                editText.setPadding(0,20,0,0);
                editText.setId(Integer.parseInt(result.getJSONObject(i).getString(config.TAG_ID)));
                editText.setEnabled(true);
                editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                editText.requestFocus();
                relativeLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
                relativeLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                relativeLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, layout.getId());
                layout.addView(editText, relativeLayoutParams);
             }
             catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with Linear Layout:

```
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.layout_items);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    JSONArray result = (JSONArray) o;
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
        EditText editText = new EditText(context);
        editText.setHint(result.getJSONObject(i).getString(config.TAG_NAME));
        editText.setPadding(0,i*100,0,0);
        editText.setId(Integer.parseInt(result.getJSONObject(i).getString(config.TAG_ID)));
        editText.setEnabled(true);
        editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        editText.requestFocus();
        editText.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        layout.addView(editText);
    }
```

And in your layout xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_items"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

use..

```
editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
editText.setFocusable(true);
editText.requestFocus();
```